# Search and Scrollbar Dropdown Submenu Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6s8zyjwm/4/). Questions:

1. I have search box in my dropdown menu and I also have multiple sub-menu. But the search box only filter on the first dropdown, the sub-menu can't work. So, how to make the search box can filter the sub-menu and show their parent like this picture?
   [image: Dropdown menu filter]
2. How to make my dropdown menu have scroll bar? I have add `overflow: auto` in CSS, but my dropdown submenu become invisible like this picture.
   [image: Submenu scrollbar]
3. How to make the dropdown submenu always on top? Same the top like its parents.
   Thank you very much. I'm using bootstrap 3.3.5.

HTML file

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> 
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">First<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Second</a>

                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>

                    <ul id="main-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class=" row search-box">
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input class="form-control search" id="search-criteria" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menu" data-toggle="dropdown">First Level</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Second Level</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menu" data-toggle="dropdown">Second Dropdown</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menu" data-toggle="dropdown">Third Dropdown</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Action</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Another action</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Separated link</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menu" data-toggle="dropdown">Another Dropdown</a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menu" data-toggle="dropdown">Level 2</a>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menu" data-toggle="dropdown">Level 3</a>

                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">One</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Two</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Three</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Four</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Five</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menu" data-toggle="dropdown">List</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menu" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menu" data-toggle="dropdown">Stationary</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Book</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Pen</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Pencil</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Ruler</a>
       

                                     </li>
                                            <li><a class="menu" href="#">Paper</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Address</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Another Project Collaboration</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

CSS file

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.search-box {
    margin: 5px 0px;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content:" ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

JS file

```
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function () {
    var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".menu").each(function () {
        var s = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        $(this).closest('.menu')[s.indexOf(g) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, have you managed to solve this problem =>  "dropdown submenu become invisible" when you applied overflow? Have you managed to make it visible at the end?

Comment: @bootsa Hi, in the end I use [smartmenus](http://www.smartmenus.org/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one :

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.search-box {
    margin: 5px 0px;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content:" ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
#wrapper .dropdown-submenu{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;


}

#container{
    width: 300px;
    transform: translate(50px, 0);

}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/6s8zyjwm/5/)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not solve my questions number 1-3 yet.

Comment: ya of cource Sir @DevanJ. if You like My answer please Up vote